# 90s illustrated horror anthology squat plump characters same era as John Bradley prominent lips

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

I got this book out a billion times from my library, I remember it was shelved right by the collection of mostly ghostly, looking at John Bradley's illustrations always makes me think of it, but I have no idea who illustrated it. All the characters were really plump and stocky. There may have been an image with the baby brother of one of them holding a blanket? For the life of me I can't remember any of the stories, only that there was one about a family that moved to a new house that was haunted. To be honest all I remember is those squat characters and these crazy mouths. I feel like all the monsters in this were not well defined but they all had these crazy insane mouths and eyes even if you couldn't see the rest of them.